# Spark multi-thread write does not work properly in cluster-mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have several [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home#Home-UserDocumentation) tables to convert in [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/) format and write down on [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html). Basically I load each one of these tables in a Spark [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes) and write it back in Parquet format. In order to parallelize even more the writing phase (a single write of a DataFrame should be already parallelized since I am using 12 executors and 5 core per executor), I've tried to spawn several threads, each thread is used to write a subset of the tables.

```
    val outputPath = "/user/xyz/testdb/tables"
    val db = "testdb"
    val partitionField = "nominal_time"
    val partition = "20180729"
    val numQueues = 6

    for (i <- 0 until numQueues) {
        val thread = new Thread {
            override def run(): Unit = {

                val tablesToProcess = queues(i)

                tablesToProcess.foreach(t => {
                    val table = t.trim.toUpperCase
                    val tempTable = "tmp_" + table
                    val destTable = table

                    var dataFrame = sqc.read.table(s"$db.$tempTable")                    

                    // write
                    dataFrame.write.
                        mode("overwrite").
                        format("parquet").
                        save(s"$outputPath/$destTable/$partitionField=$partition")

                    println(s"\n\nWrite completed for table $table\n")
                })
            }
        }
        thread.start()
    }
```

This code is working fine in YARN-CLIENT mode and I can observe a significant reduction of the time required for the process to complete.
The thing I don't uderstand is when I launch the same code in YARN-CLUSTER mode, the job completes very fast (too fast I have to say) but it does not write anything.
Am I missing something fundamental here that causes a multi-thread spark program to not work properly in cluster mode?

Comment: there is a ton of possible issues that can be attributed to this problem. Your really should look at the logs and understand why it crashes. because there is no real reason if everything is configured correctly that a job will work in client-mode but not in cluster-mode.

Comment: @IlyaBrodezki Everything should be configured correctly since I can run several Spark programs in both client and cluster mode and obtain the same result. It's only for this specific case, where I am using multi-threading, that I am experiencing a different behavior between client and cluster mode.

Comment: as I said there can be a ton of issues for example your definition of the hdfs connection in the spark can depend on something local which the cluster doesnt have. I have code that does most of what you're trying to do in cluster mode. did you look at the logs? what do you see if you run: 
yarn logs -applicationId <app_id> | grep ERROR?
does your run even finish with a SUCCESS tag?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Hive table"_ vs _"Parquet format"_?!? A simple Hive query is enough to push raw CSV-based data into Parquet-based data.